# namespaces: using System & using System.IO

Tags: c#, namespaces

so my program has these 2 lines at the beginning

```
using System;
using System.IO;
```

Question: Is the second statement actually necessary  to include Sytem.IO methods and properties in my code?
 It seems that 'System.IO'  is  a 'child' of the namespace 'System'. Shouldn't the first line grab all the child namespaces too? Or Do I not understand namespaces correctly?

Comment: If System.IO is a separate namespace than why not just call it 'IO"?

Comment: Resharper will help you to know how necesary it is

Comment: There could also be a namespace called `External.IO`, for instance. So you need the complete spec to identify the namespace.

Comment: could it be said that System.IO inherits from System? then I guess it would make sense

Comment: @LoganBender No, there's no inheritance.  Namespaces are logical groupings of related classes, and don't reflect a physical hierarchy of inheritance.

Answer (score 5):

`System.IO` namespace is used for `Input Output` operations.(Ex: `File` Operations)

`System` namespace does not include all child namespaces.
So if you want to perform `IO` Operations you should include `System.IO` namespace `explicitly`.

> First Question :   Is the second statement actually necessary to
>   include Sytem.IO methods and properties in my code?

**Yes** it is Necessary as `System` namespace does not include `Child` namespaces.

> Second Question :  It seems that 'System.IO' is a 'child' of the
>   namespace 'System'.

**Yes** `System.IO` is a Child of `System` namespace.

Note : though `System.IO` is a child namspace of `System`, it will not be included when you include `System` namspace

> Third Question : Shouldn't the first line grab all the child
>   namespaces too? Or Do I not understand namespaces correctly?

**No** first line `using System;` does not grab all the Child namespaces as it is not `java` to `import` all `child` namspeaces using wild card character star `*`

Answer (score 2):

C# is not like java, where you can use wildcards to import namespaces.

```
using System;
```

in C# is not the same as

```
import system.*;
```

in Java.

And that's really all there is to it.  You need to explicitly include namespaces - not much more to say about it :)

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the first line grab all the child namespaces too? Or Do I not understand namespaces correctly?

No - it will only make an alias for types in the `System` namespace *directly*.  "Nested" namespaces (such as `System.IO`) are not made aliases automatically in C#.  This is mentioned in [the help for the `using directive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) (italics added by me for emphasis):

> allow the use of types in a namespace so that you do not have to qualify the use of a type *in that namespace*

You would still need to qualify `IO` for `IO` operations.  For example, if you wanted to use the `Path` class, you'd need:

```
var filename = System.IO.Path.GetFilename(fullPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answers, there really aren't "child namespaces". There's nothing stopping you from declaring your own `System.IO`. You wouldn't want to of course, but you don't need a parent `System` namespace to do it.

You may have a project that by default has `MyCompany.MyProject` namespace, but you could just as easily declare `XYZ.Some.Other.Random.Namespace` in another .cs file of the same project. There's no inheritance to namespaces and `XYZ.Some.Other` doesn't exist. C# will let you use it, however, when you try to instantiate your class using the rest of it (`Random.Namespace`), it doesn't know how to find the class and won't resolve until you fully qualify the namespace in the `using` or fully qualify your variable declaration.